# Formtastic Number format decimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

I'm trying

```
<%= f.input :provvigioni, :as => :number, :input_html => {:value =>      number_with_precision(f.object.provvigioni, precision: 2)} %>
```

Why edit have scrollbar????? I use formstatic & formtastic bootstrap 
Thank's in advanced. Aesis.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
:as => :string
```

It will still accept decimal values